# Cloud9 changing workspace tree

Tags: cloud9-ide

I'm working on my own dev server connected to Cloud9 via SSH.
My server hosts multiple projects but I access them all through the same workspace which points to the users root (~) on the machine.
Problem is, the workspace directory tree on the left side of the screen grows bigger and bigger with every project I add and it's getting confusing (tasks like wide file search and jumping between files especially).

Is there a way to change the project tree on the left? In Sublime I would just go to the project directory and type `subl .`

Thanks,
Pavel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your home directory would look something like:

```
- ~
  - project1
  - project2
  - project3
  - project4
```

You just need to adjust the initial path of each workspace to start with something like:

```
/home/myAwesomeUserName/project1
```

And that project directory will then become the root directory for that workspace. I'm attaching a screenshot to help you locate where it is within the SSH settings/creation dialog:

[image]